# how to redirect in a laravel application after sharing in facebook

Tags: php, facebook, laravel-5, facebook-sharer, facebook-share

I am working in a laravel 5.4 project. So in the process I had to create a facebook share button. The problem is it is getting shared successfully but after sharing it is showing some url like this

> **[https://www.facebook.com/dialog/return/close#*=*](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/return/close#_=_)**
>   which is an empty page. how can i set here a redirection link.
>   Here is my button

```
 <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://pustokbd.com/blogs/{{$Blog->parma_link}}"  data-layout="button_count" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
```

Comment: `{{ urlencode('http://pustokbd.com/blogs/'.$Blog->parma_link)  }}` of sorts.

Comment: sorry i didn't get your comment

Comment: You need to pass an encoded url to share link eg: `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fpustokbd.com%2Fblogs%2Ffoobar`

Comment: but that does not solve the redirection problem

Comment: You should open it in a popup using javascript, as after posted it redirects to the link above which has `window.close()`, but it wont work on a tab so its just an empty page.

Comment: sharer.php is an outdated script, use the current URL redirect version of the Share dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#redirect